# Mule esb 3.8 how to add variable into payload?

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

let say I have payload:

> {    Name=User1,    Age=29 }

and variable:

> { Address=Planet Earth}

I want to have a check if that variable not null then add it into payload.
So final result will be:

> { Name=User1, Age=29, Address=Planet Earth }

How? Was try via payload.Put(variable) but that not allow me such.

Comment: What are the payload and variable Java classes?

Comment: as normaly hashmaps objects, variable content from another payload as after call to db its overwrites and I want merge both calls to db results into one, final payload

Comment: HashMap.put() expects a key and value, not another map. See my answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DataWeave using a Transform component you can use the expression: `payload ++ flowVars.variable`

If you don't want or can't use DataWeave then you can use a MEL expression that uses the Java method `Map.putAll()` of the Map interface. You can not use `<set-payload>` because it doesn't return a value. Instead you can use the `<expression-component>` component.

Example:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload.putAll(flowVars.variable)]]></expression-component>
```

Comment: I updated the answer with a non DataWeave solution.

Comment: supper that even better. I was try call dw in mel like: dw("payload ++ flowVars.variable") but it don't like it

Comment: I recommend to avoid mixing languages in the same expression. DataWeave hides the complexity of the types and implementation classes. DataWeave 2 in Mule 4 is even more powerful. MEL is a scripting language based in Java syntax instead.

Comment: could you advice how to do same but with linked list? 1st payload kind of same but 2nd is now similar to 1st and need nest it to got: {Name=User1, Age=29, Address=[{Planet = Earth, Continent = Europa, Town = London},{Planet = Earth, Continent = Europa, Town = Dublin}]}?

Comment: Open a new question please.